# How do I change the owner of an ENS domain using MyEtherWallet?

Tags: contract-invocation, myetherwallet, ens

Does anyone know the exact procedure for doing this? It looks quite straightforward, but I'm unwilling to try it out without confirmation from someone who's done it already.

Answer (score 13):

Instructions for [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com/) & MyEtherWallet

#### Transferring a Domain (Best Practice)

1. Search for your ENS name on [MyCrypto's ENS Page](https://mycrypto.com/ens)
2. Copy the text to the right of `Labelhash __name:`.
3. Go to the [Contracts](https://mycrypto.com/contracts/interact) page and select `ENS - Eth Registrar (Auction) 0x6090a6e47849629b7245dfa1ca21d94cd15878ef` from the dropdown menu.
4. Access and choose the `transfer` call. Paste the `LabelHash` from step #2 above into the `_hash` field.
5. Paste the `address` of the new owner in the `newOwner` field.
6. Unlock your wallet and send.

---

#### Only setting Owner

*WARNING: If you only change the owner, the deed owner can get the name back.*

1. Search for your ENS name on [MyCrypto's ENS Page](https://mycrypto.com/ens)
2. Copy the text to the right of `Namehash __name.eth:`.
3. Go to the [Contracts](https://mycrypto.com/contracts/interact) page and select `ENS Registry (0x314159265dD8dbb310642f98f50C066173C1259b)` from the dropdown menu.
4. Access and choose the `setOwner` call. Paste the `NameHash` (not LabelHash) from step #2 into the `node` field.
5. Paste the `address` of the new owner in owner.
6. Unlock your wallet and rock and roll.

(Thanks for the help, [/u/feauxley](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6d01r1/changing_ens_owner_address_using_myetherwallet/))

Comment: This is completely outdated

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [MEW Contracts page](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#contracts) and select "ENS Registry" from the dropdown menu.

Access and choose the setOwner call. Paste the NameHash (not LabelHash) from [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/enslookup) into the node field.

Paste the address of the new owner in owner.

setOwner function changes ownership of the name (e.g. the ability to point to a resolver), but not ownership of the deed that bought the name (the ability to release the deed to auction and reclaim the funds). To transfer ownership of the deed itself, call the transfer function of the ENS - Eth Registrar Auction, this time with the LabelHash.

Source : [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/6d01r1/changing_ens_owner_address_using_myetherwallet/)